# Simple Flutter list view choppy scrolling

Tags: performance, flutter

I've been evaluating Flutter for use in an app and started with a very simple example of a list of text. After building this first view, I noticed the list view had choppy scrolling so I looked closer at the showcase apps and it turns out that while [Reflectly](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reflectly-journal-diary/id1241229134?mt=8), for example, is a beautiful app, it suffers from the same problem - very choppy scrolling with a simple list of text. So far I have confirmed this on the iOS simulator, an iPhone XR, Samsung Galaxy Android device and Android Pixel 2 XL simulator.

I don't see discussions around this so I wonder if I'm doing something wrong but also skeptical I am given how simple my example is and that Reflectly has the same issue.

What I'd love from the community is to understand:
1. Am I doing anything obviously wrong / stupid to cause this
2. If you run on your device, do you see what I see?
3. Is this known and will be worked on? If I commit to Flutter, can I feel comfortable that my lists will scroll smoothly in the near future?

Below is the code you can run to reproduce this (sorry it's a bit contrived but I wanted to play around with various Flutter/Dart features):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My List',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My List'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.9),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: TimeSelector()),
            ],
          )),
        ));
  }
}

abstract class ListItem {}

class TimeHeader implements ListItem {
  final String header;

  TimeHeader(this.header);
}

class TimeOption implements ListItem {
  final String timeString;
  final String meridian;

  TimeOption(this.timeString, this.meridian);
}

final List<ListItem> litems = [
  TimeHeader("Morning"),
  TimeOption("10:00", "am"),
  TimeOption("10:30", "am"),
  TimeOption("11:30", "am"),
  TimeHeader("Afternoon"),
  TimeOption("1:00", "pm"),
  TimeOption("1:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("2:30", "pm"),
  TimeHeader("Night"),
  TimeOption("5:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("6:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("7:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("8:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("9:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("10:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("11:30", "pm"),
  TimeOption("11:45", "pm"),
  TimeOption("11:49", "pm"),
];

class TimeSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  final _headerFont = new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 13.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(164, 164, 164, 1));
  final _smallerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0);

  @override
  ListView build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemCount: litems.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => _buildItem(ctxt, index),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
    final item = litems[index];

    if (item is TimeHeader) {
      return new ListTile(
        title: Text(
          item.header,
          style: _headerFont,
        ),
      );
    } else if (item is TimeOption) {
      return new ListTile(
        title: Text(
          item.timeString + item.meridian.toUpperCase(),
          style: _smallerFont,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return new Text("UNKNOWN");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: code seems fine but what you exact mean by choppy scrolling ?

Comment: tested your code on my simulators work as excepted has no apparent issues.

Comment: choppy means it does not scroll smooth, it jumps a little bit. you have to pay close attention to notice it and it's a little more apparent on the iphone / iOS simulator. scroll slowly and you'll see that it feels like frames are being skipped

Comment: are you in release mode ?

Comment: your code should work fine in release mode

Comment: is release mode the same as running without debug? or must i have it signed for release?

Comment: i think `flutter run --release path/to/your/program.dart` is enough (check the apk size: if its 25 MB its debug, 5 MB otherwise)

Comment: Hmmm well it's definitely performing much better! Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I also facing the same issue. is there any way to solve this problem in Debug mode only? @RaoufRahiche

Comment: I've noticed the same thing even when I'm in release mode. Scrolling a basic listview with like 10 items is just not smooth. I guess that's still the benefit of going true native with swift/objective c. I hope google can fix this. @Tony any updates on this since you asked this question?

Comment: This is an issue that happens in some devices only, that's why some of you may see it and others don't. I have a brand new iPhone XR and even on --release i see the scrolling choppy, specially when the speed of scroll is low, if you are scrolling very fast is less noticeable

Answer (score 9):

Flutter ListView definitely has an issue in scrolling in debug mode. Although your code will run properly in release mode, without any lag in the scroll. But, still, if you want to scroll without any lag in debug mode, you can prefer **SingleChildScrollView** over ListView. Just put your scrolling widgets in a Column and put that Column as the child of SingleChildScrollView.
In your case, you are using **ListView.builder** . I will suggest you should use this code to achieve a very smooth scroll:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              itemCount: litems.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => _buildItem(ctxt, index),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Don't forget to use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` as column size and `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

**physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()** will disable the scroll of your ListView.builder and you will experience an extremely smooth scroll of your list

Comment: Althought this solution works good but the drawback of this solution comes out in performance because the whole list renders once. so we can see the lag clearly in app. Simple words it increase the loading time

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with static data of very low number of list items, you can speed the list up using `addAutomaticKeepAlives: true`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix choppy scrolling on iOS by disabling the Impeller rendering backend.

To disable Impeller on iOS, add the following tags under the top-level tag in your app’s Info.plist file.

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
<false />
```